# JDB doesn't work when attaching to a running Android process

Tags: java, android, debugging, adb

I want to attach debugger to running android application on a physical device connected through USB.
The device is rooted using magisk. The `ro.debuggable` property also set to `1` using `resetprop` to make all apps debuggable.

For example, the app will be calculator (`com.android.calculator2`).

The exact steps I did:

1. `adb kill-server`
   Make sure to restart the adb server.
2. `adb devices` Start the server again and make sure the device is authorized.
3. Run the app (calculator in my example).
4. `adb shell ps | grep calculator` Find the app ID.

   ```
   u0_a88        4445 16282 4193244 133532 0                   0 S com.android.calculator2
   ```

   The app ID is 4445.
5. `adb jdwp | grep 4445` Make sure the app id is in the debuggable applications list.
   Output: `4445`. So the app is debuggable.
6. `adb forward tcp:7777 jdwp:4445` Forward `7777` local tcp port to jdwp.
7. `jdb -attach localhost:7777` Connect JDB to the port.

And here is the problem. At the last step nothing happens. JDB doesn't exit nor connect, also it doesn't output anything on any input command.

I also tried Android Studio. I tried two options. Manually add configuration to connect to remote JVM and use `Attach Debugger to Android Process` option.
The first option (connect to remote JVM configuration) doesn't work. I used this command line flags: `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:7777`. Port forwarding is done the same way. Android Studio as well does not connect nor exit or print error. Just nothing.

But the `Attach Debugger to Android Process` option works great. It successfully connects to the app and I can debug it and set breakpoints as expected.

I also want to mention that I used `am set-debug-app` command before to make the app wait for the debugger to connect before start. When either `jdb` from command line or Android Studio remote connect to JVM option is used, the app doesn't resume, so it seems like Android doesn't see the debugger at all. But when I connect the debugger via `Attach Debugger to Android Process`, the app resumes after attaching the debugger as expected.

Why JDB does not attach to the app while Android Studio does via option `Attach Debugger to Android Process`?
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you also have Android Studio running. Studio monitors all debuggable process via `track-jdwp` and redirect the jdwp traffic to itself to keep tabs on the app lifecycle (via DDMS).

Close Android Studio and try the same `jdb` command again.